# Constructor not found?

Tags: c#

Somehow the constructor in one of my classes isnt being found with the parameters...
Has anyone experienced this?

Here is my code and how I am calling it:

MoveFiles class:

```
class MoveFiles
{
    #region Variables

    //Variables
    public string strSrcPath, strDstPath, strFdrName, strNewDestFldrPath = "";
    Main frm = new Main();

    #endregion

    #region Constructor

    //Constructor - accepts the path and store the value
    private void MoveFiles(string strSourcePath, string strDestPath, string strFldrName)
    {
        strSrcPath = strSourcePath;
        strDstPath = strDestPath;
        strFdrName = strFldrName;
    }

    #endregion     
    ETC....
```

then here is where I am calling it:

```
//move the files based on the source path, destination path, and folder name
MoveFiles moveFile = new MoveFiles(strSrcPath, strDestPath, strFoldrName); 
moveFile.StartMove();
```

The place of where I am calling it gives me an error that the constructor doesn't take three arguments....

Anyone have an issue like this and how did you fix it?
Or am i just blind and is there sometihng really going on there?

Comment: The constructor shouldn't have a return type, and if you want to call it from another class, it has to not be `private`.

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio? I would expect quite a few errors/warnings as to what is wrong with your code other than the line you are trying to call it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace `private void MoveFiles` by `public MoveFiles`

Comment: Thank you. I actually had it as that before, it was giving me some strange error this morning such as "member modifier public must precede the member type and name". Maybe it was just being super fussy?

Answer (score 4):

Change constructor as

```
public MoveFiles(string strSourcePath, string strDestPath, string strFldrName)
{
    strSrcPath = strSourcePath;
    strDstPath = strDestPath;
    strFdrName = strFldrName;
}
```

`private void` means that this is Instance Method, not a constructor. And constructors don't have return types.

Answer (score 1):

Your constructor is private

```
private void MoveFiles(string strSourcePath, string strDestPath, string strFldrName)
{
 .....
}
```

change it to public (also constructors do not have return type):

```
public MoveFiles(string strSourcePath, string strDestPath, string strFldrName)
{
 .....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to the fact that you made the constructor `private` and not `public` or `protected`

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are instantiating the class from within itself, you won't be able to as the overloaded constructor is private, mark it `public` instead. And remove the return type `void`.

Answer (score 0):

Constructors don't have return types. Remote the `void`:

```
//Constructor - accepts the path and store the value
private MoveFiles(string strSourcePath, string strDestPath, string strFldrName)
{
    strSrcPath = strSourcePath;
    strDstPath = strDestPath;
    strFdrName = strFldrName;
}
```

Also note, that private constructor may only be called within the same class. You may have meant to make this public.